# Would this tell me if this value is in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable located inside an array and I'm wondering if this would tell me if that variable: `FRT_SOLID` is in an array?

```js
(arr.some((elem) => elem == "FRT_SOLID"))
```

If so, would this tell me if `FRT_SOLID` nowhere in the array?

```js
(arr.some((elem) => elem != "FRT_SOLID"))
```

Comment: in order to give the exact answer to this, you may need to tell us what sort of object is in the array. Normally, yes, that works.

Comment: why not simply use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)? :)

Comment: It actually depends.

Comment: pls share a sample array

Comment: 1. do you mean you "have a **value** located inside an array"?

Comment: 2. do you mean "If so, would this tell me if FRT_SOLID is **not** in an array?"?

Comment: 2.a. if so, then `(!arr.some((elem) => elem == "FRT_SOLID"))` should be used.

Comment: @TonyCodesDaily When you try this code yourself, what happens?

Comment: @IAmOren Yes sorry for the typo guys I meant to say "If so, would this tell me if FRT_SOLID is not in an array? I have since edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following if that is creating an problem

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

var n = fruits.includes("Mango");`
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example is wrong, as it will be `true` if there is any element in the array that is not equal to the specified one. It should be written as this instead:

```
!arr.some((elem) => elem === "FRT_SOLID")
```

Of course, it much easier and clearer to use `Array#includes`.

```
!arr.includes("FRT_SOLID")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use indexOf if you need the current index of the element. If the element is not available in the array it will return -1.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log(fruits.indexOf("Mango")); // returns 3
console.log(fruits.indexOf("Grape")); // returns -1
```